# Небольшие изменения сильно замедлили выполнение запроса к базе

Tags: sql, firebird

Такая проблема: есть первоначальный запрос, где для выборки используется GUID, который выполняется очень быстро ~ 100-200 ms. И есть второй запрос, где для выборки используется другое уникальное поле, но скорость выборки уменьшилась в несколько сотен раз. Индексы на каждую колонку стоят. При выполнении запросов очень сильно различается скорость их выполнения.

Статистические данные:

1. Выполнение запросов - первый за 100 ms, второй за 6000-7000 ms.
2. Первый выполняется по GUID, второй по другому уникальному полю.
3. Количество записей в базе данных около одного миллиона.
4. Если из второго запроса убрать конструкцию Order by, то скорость увеличится примерно в 10 раз, но мне нужно, чтобы записи были отсортированы.

Вопрос: Что еще нужно вам для правильного анализа и ответа на мой вопрос?

1 запрос:

```
select 
  ADDROBJECT.NAME,
  ADDROBJECT.ID,
  ADDROBJECT.ID as masterid2,
  ADDROBJECT.PARENTID, 
  ADDROBJECT.KINDID,
  ADDROBJECT.ELEMENTID, 
  LONGSTRREPLACE(ADDRKIND.FORMAT, '%s%', ADDROBJECT.NAME), 
  LONGSTRREPLACE(ADDRKIND.FORMAT, '%s%', ADDROBJECT.NAME) as text
from ADDROBJECT 
inner join ADDRKIND 
  on ADDROBJECT.KINDID = ADDRKIND.ID
where ADDROBJECT.PARENTID=:masterid AND
      (ADDROBJECT.RECVALID IS NULL OR ADDROBJECT.RECVALID <> '51') AND
      ADDROBJECT.KLADRCODE IS NOT NULL
order by ADDROBJECT.NAME
```

2 запрос: тот, который нужно ускорить:

```
select
  ADDROBJECT.NAME,
  ADDROBJECT.ID,
  ADDROBJECT.ID as masterid2,
  ADDROBJECT.PARENTID, 
  ADDROBJECT.KINDID,
  ADDROBJECT.ELEMENTID, 
  LONGSTRREPLACE(ADDRKIND.FORMAT, '%s%', ADDROBJECT.NAME), 
  LONGSTRREPLACE(ADDRKIND.FORMAT, '%s%', ADDROBJECT.NAME) as text
from ADDROBJECT 
inner join ADDRKIND 
  on ADDROBJECT.KINDID = ADDRKIND.ID
where (ADDROBJECT.RECVALID IS NULL OR ADDROBJECT.RECVALID <> '51') AND
      (select * from GETPARENTCODE(ADDROBJECT.kladrcode)) = 
      (select SUBSTRING(a.kladrcode FROM 1 FOR 11)
       from addrobject a
       where a.id=:masterid)
order by text asc
```

GETPARENTCODE - функция для получения parent кода для записи по такому же коду этой записи. Данный код используется в КЛАДРе. Например, у записи код - "3800401200000". Через эту функцию я получу код, который у родителя, то есть "38004000000" только без двух последних символов, которые не нужны для запроса:

```
begin
  strlength = CHAR_LENGTH(KLADRCODE);
  if (strlength = 17) then begin
    PARENTCODE = SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 1 FOR 11);
  end else begin
    PARTPARENTCODE = SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 3 FOR 3);
    if (PARTPARENTCODE NOT LIKE '000') then begin
      PARENTCODE = (SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 1 FOR 2)) || '000000000';
    end

    PARTPARENTCODE = SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 6 FOR 3);
    if (PARTPARENTCODE NOT LIKE '000') then begin
      PARENTCODE = (SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 1 FOR 5)) || '000000';
    end

    PARTPARENTCODE = SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 9 FOR 3);
    if (PARTPARENTCODE NOT LIKE '000') then begin
      PARENTCODE = (SUBSTRING(:KLADRCODE FROM 1 FOR 8)) || '000';
    end
  end

  SUSPEND;
end
```

Comment: Что такое `GETPARENTCODE`?

Comment: Второй содержит "процедуру" GETPARENTCODE - которая неизвесно что делает. Возможно лучше её убрать. Переписать на join. Делать join по ключевым полям.

Comment: @nick_n_a, добавил описание процедуры (просто, чтобы была), убрать нельзя, потому что она выполняет тот код, который нужен для выборки

Comment: Не понятно что делает процедура, почему like не содержит подстановочных символов. Я бы посоветовал переписать процедуру на `case  when  условие then случай1 else случай2 end`

Comment: @nick_n_a, добавил краткое описание, что делает функция, но суть то в самом запросе ... не трогайте функцию, быстрее она работать не станет, точно не на несколько секунд

Comment: Тогда у вас остается одно - проверить ключевание по полям по которым у вас идёт выборка. это всё. ADDROBJECT.KINDID, ADDROBJECT.ID, ADDROBJECT.RECVALID, addrobject.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброе утро.

Это условие:

```
(select * from GETPARENTCODE(ADDROBJECT.kladrcode)) = 
  (select SUBSTRING(a.kladrcode FROM 1 FOR 11)
   from addrobject a
   where a.id=:masterid)
```

создаёт проблемы со скоростью, так как заставляет просматривать все строки в таблице при запросе. Условно говоря, чтобы найти строки, в которых преобразованная часть поля kladrcode соответсвует части этого же поля по одной из строк таблицы придётся один раз получить данные по строке с :masterid, потом уже ходить по всей таблице и сравнивать полученное значение с преобразованным полем kladrcode.

Чтобы было быстро, следует задействовать индекс. Чтобы задействовать индекс, можно сделать ещё одно поле, назвать, например parentcode и туда сразу же при вставке сохранять результат GETPARENTCODE(kladrcode). И на это поле повесить индекс. Тогда условие можно будет преобразовать вот так:

```
parentcode = 
  (select SUBSTRING(a.kladrcode FROM 1 FOR 11)
   from addrobject a
   where a.id=:masterid)
```

Уже имеющиеся строки можно обновить чем-то вроде этого:

```
UPDATE ADDROBJECT SET parentcode = GETPARENTCODE(kladrcode)
```